# Symfony2: How to pass url querystring parameters to controllers?

Tags: url, symfony, parameters, routes, query-string

Maybe I am missing something but there doesn't seem to be a way to define querystring parameters in routes in Symfony2 so that they can be passed into a controller.

For instance, instead of generating a URI like `/blog/my-blog-post` (from Symfony2's [routing documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/routing.html)) and passing it to the following route:

```
# app/config/routing.yml    
blog_show:
    pattern:   /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

I would prefer to generate a URI like `/blog?slug=my-blog-post`. The problem is I can't find anywhere to define the `slug` parameter in the route configuration file (like its {slug} counterpart above).

Perhaps this is on purpose but then what is the best practice for working with GET parameters in the querystring?

The documentation does make mention of them in [Generating URLs with Query Strings](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings), so how to pass them into the controller?

Where I can find mention of them is [Symfony2 and HTTP Fundamentals](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

// retrieve GET variables
$request->query->get('foo');
```

Is this the best practice for working with them inside the controller?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To work with GET / POST parameters in a controller that extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $request->query->get('myParam'); // get a $_GET parameter
    $request->request->get('myParam'); // get a $_POST parameter
    ...
}
```

For a controller which does not extend the Symfony base controller, declare the request object as a parameter of the action method and proceed as above:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $request->query->get('myParam'); // get a $_GET parameter
    $request->request->get('myParam'); // get a $_POST parameter
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since Symfony 2.4, the `getRequest()` method is now deprecated and one should use the second trick, with the `Request` parameter in the controller method. the `getRequest()` method will be removed in Symfony 3.

Comment: @Brewal: but if you have a `Controller` that extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` and which already gets parameters as defined in its route, can you still also get the Request this way or do you simply have to use `Request::createFromGlobals()` now?

Comment: You can still get the request thanks to the `Request` type specified just before the `$request` variable. Symfony is smart enough to guess that.

Answer (score 30):

You can't specify your query string parameters in the routing configuration files.
You just get them from the $request object in your controller: `$request->query->get('foo');`
 (will be `null` if it doesn't exist).

And to generate a route with a given parameter, you can do it in you twig templates like that :

```
{{ path(route, query|merge({'page': 1})) }}
```

If you want to generate a route in your controller, it's just like in the documentation you linked:

```
$router->generate('blog', array('page' => 2, 'category' => 'Symfony'));
```

will generate the route `/blog/2?category=Symfony` (the parameters that don't exist in the route definition will be passed as query strings).

Comment: Documentation: [generating-urls-with-query-strings](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-with-query-strings)